# check if ip address belongs to a Class A, B and C in python

Tags: python, ip

How can determine class of IP address in python. I am working with ipaddress module of python.
Following are class definitions

```
Class   Private Networks    Subnet Mask Address Range
A   10.0.0.0    255.0.0.0   10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255
B   172.16.0.0 - 172.31.0.0 255.240.0.0 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
C   192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255
```

Given a IP how can I check if it belongs to Class A, B or C

Comment: Do you just want to see whether the IP [`is_private`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address.is_private)? Because the definition of class A, B, C etc is outdated and not used anymore (see classless IP addresses) and in any case the definition included non-private IPs too.

Comment: I want to categorize private IPs into classes but couldn't find a way

Comment: maybe this a stupid idea, but what about string-comparison? A/B/C all have different rangers (first 3 numbers) - wouldnt it be possible to differentiate by that? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: @Cribber a given IP may be putside of those 3 classes

Comment: Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (two years before the 1995 commercial Internet!) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Network classes have not been used in this century.

Answer (score 5):

### IPv4

Use `ipaddress.IPv4Address` and `ipaddress.IPv4Network` types.

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Address, IPv4Network

classA = IPv4Network(("10.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0"))  # or IPv4Network("10.0.0.0/8")
classB = IPv4Network(("172.16.0.0", "255.240.0.0"))  # or IPv4Network("172.16.0.0/12")
classC = IPv4Network(("192.168.0.0", "255.255.0.0"))  # or IPv4Network("192.168.0.0/16")
```

I gave you the tuple form as you have the network address and mask but if you prefer the /X (CIDR standard) suffix it also accepts it. There are actually some additional ways.

To use it you will just check if a certain `IPv4Address` is `in` the `IPv4Network` as if you were checking in an element is found inside a `list`:

```
ip1 = IPv4Address("10.0.2.8")
ip2 = IPv4Address("172.18.76.25")
ip3 = IPv4Address("192.168.45.62")

ip1 in classA  # True
ip2 in classA  # False
ip3 in classA  # False

ip1 in classB  # False
ip2 in classB  # True
ip3 in classB  # False

ip1 in classC  # False
ip2 in classC  # False
ip3 in classC  # True
```

### IPv6

Use `ipaddress.IPv6Address` and `ipaddress.IPv6Network` types instead and correct IPv6 ip strings when creating the objects.

### Generic

If both supporting IPv4 and IPv6 is desired, `ipaddress.ip_address` and `ipaddress.ip_network` convenience factory functions can be used, and the module will create the appropiate IPv4 or IPv6 class depending on the string format.

---

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html

Comment: This looks good. Can we check classes in IPv6 in this way? Can you give any example

Comment: There are equivalent classes for IPv6, `ipaddress.IPv6Address` and `ipaddress.IPv6Network`, but haven't tried them, will give them a shot and post back, but I expect a similar behaviour

Comment: As expected, those classes work exactly the same as IPv4 versions.

Comment: Information about IPv6 and generic versions included in the asnwer. Aside from Address and Network classes, there is a third one, Interface that basically groups both previous classes, meant to specify a device IP + the network it is connected to in a single object, take a look if it may help in your application.

Comment: @Adirio this is good for a single subnet , how do we cover the whole range of IP address in a particular class.

Comment: @KrishnaOza Do you mean having a `classAandBandC` variable that checks if it belongs to any of the 3? I don't think you can combine `IPv4Network` objects together. I would probably define a `is_class_a`, `is_class_b`, `is_class_c` and `is_class_a_b_c` functions that do this check for me by just joining the checks in this answer with `or`.

Comment: "_There are equivalent classes for IPv6_" No, there are not. IPv4 network classes were deprecated two years before IPv6, and IPv6 has _always_ been classless, as has IPv4 since 1993.

Comment: @RonMaupin I was talking about classes as a programming construct. `IPv4Network` is a class, and its v6 equivalent is `IPv6Network`.

Comment: Please be aware that not everything is fine with this question and answer.
The answer tells if an address belongs to one of private class A/B/C networks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network. Full class A/B/C networks have bigger scope (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network) and the answer don't cover determining them.

Comment: @RobertGomułka the question is talking about private networks as it can be seen by the ranges provided in it, despite not using the term "private networks". Variables `classA`, `classB` & `classC` are defined consequently. If you want to adapt the answer to cover "classful networks" (which by the way are way less common) just modify the definition of those variables to use the values of the start address and the subnetwork mask as provided in the link table: `classA = IPv4Network(("0.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0"))` would be the first one for example.

Comment: @RobertGomułka additionally, the question and the answer are perfectly fine. Not being exactly your case doesn't make them inherently wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check if IP address belongs to class A, B, or C in Python:

```
a='195.168.10.20'
b=int(a[0:3])
if b in range(1,127):
    print(a,'-->','class-A')
elif b in range(128,191):
    print(a,'-->','class-B')
elif b in range(192,223):
    print(a,'-->','class-C')
elif b in range (224,239):
    print(a,'-->','class-D')
elif b in range (240,255):
    print(a,'-->','class-E')
else:
    print(a,'-->','not valid ip')
```

Output:

```
195.168.10.20 --> class-C
```