# How to get subnet mask though Python?

Tags: python, networking, ip, broadcast, ipv4

I want to send a broadcast message over a network using Python. I have code for finding the IP address of my computer, and I know how to calculate the broadcast IP given an IP address and a subnet mask, but I cannot figure out how to get the subnet mask in the first place. I looked through the socket and ipaddress modules, but couldn't identify anything that would give me what I want(not to say it doesn't exist!). Here is what I have so far if that helps.

```
import socket

hostname = socket.gethostname()
IP = socket.gethostfromname(hostname)

if IP.startswith('192.168') == True:
    Sub = '255.255.0.0'
else:
    Sub = '255.255.255.0'

def get_ID(ip, mask):
    ip = ip.split('.')
    mask = mask.split('.')
    ip = [int(bin(int(octet)), 2) for octet in ip]
    mask = [int(bin(int(octet)), 2) for octet in mask]
    broadcast = [(ioctet | ~moctet) & 0xff for ioctet, moctet in zip(ip, mask)]
    broadcast = str(broadcast[0]) + '.' + str(broadcast[1]) + '.' + str(broadcast[2]) + '.' + str(broadcast[3])
    return broadcast

broadcastaddr = get_ID(IP, Sub)
```

If I had a sure fire way to get the subnet mask, this would be much less likely to fail on a general computer.

Comment: Side note: Never do `if foo == True`. Use `is` instead of `==` to compare singletons, but in the case of `True` just do `if foo`.

Comment: Check out the [`ipaddress` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#module-ipaddress) to simplify some of your manual logic

Comment: I did; I was unable to identify a way to use it though.

Comment: At the _very_ least you can stop doing things like `int(bin(int(octet)))`... That would be a huge win.

Comment: See also [check if ip address belongs to a Class A, B and C in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42385606/354577)

Comment: How about situations where the subnet mask is _not_ the default? For example, if an admin decides to split their class C network into four subnets with different subnet masks? Or am I misunderstanding the operation of the broadcast address; if I used the default class C subnet mask to calculate the broadcast IP address in a divided subnet, would it be acknowledged in all divisions of the subnet, or would it be ignored outside the division it was sent from?

Comment: Also, I will be updating the above code as I streamline it; right now it is pretty rough I admit. Sorry for the painful looking nested functions. I can tell my code is hurting your eyes.

Comment: How does your _existing_ code handle this? I'm just giving you some pointers to improve what you're showing.

Comment: The snippet I sent originally (with the flash edit for converting to str) worked on my computer, but I need to generalize it for systems I can't interact with.

Comment: There's no way to get another machine's configured network mask from their IP address. There's no guarantee that the IP address you get is even assigned to the machine you're talking to. It's very likely that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: My general goal is to make an application send a broadcast message to **local hosts** and find ones that respond to a certain message, then create a list of those IP addresses. I think it is fairly safe to assume a class C network for this, but since I don't know for sure what the network will be I don't want to write code that isn't generalized. This is why I specifically am looking for a way to find the subnet mask; since I already have the IP, this will give me the broadcast address.

Comment: I think the only thing you can do is use the conventional rules and allow the user to override it by _providing_ a network mask.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I will use your suggestion.